# Sending json data from localhost Jupyter notebook to vue page

Tags: python, vue.js, jupyter-notebook, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Trying to access data stored in `/api/python/index.ts` from the localhost python post request.

Receiving a GET method not allowed error

Error Message:

```
405 (HTTP method is not allowed.)
```

I'm trying to fetch json data stored in the `index.ts` from `index.vue`.

The data is posted from a localhost Jupyter notebook python script.

**Python post request code:**

```py
url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/python'
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post(url, json=top_4_json, headers=headers)
print(response.json())
```

Output:

```
{'data': '[{"id": 24, "value": 0.04}, {"id": 25, "value": 0.04}, {"id": 45, "value": 0.03}]'}
```

**/api/python/index.ts**

```js
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const body = await readBody(event)
    console.log(body)
    return { body }
})
```

Console log:

```
[{"id": 24, "value": 0.04}, {"id": 25, "value": 0.04}, {"id": 45, "value": 0.03}]
```

**/pages/index.vue**

```
export default {
    setup() {
        const { data } = useFetch('/api/python/')
        return { data }
```

**error 405 http method is not allowed**

After edit:

thanks for the replies.

Comment: I think your example is not complete, but I have a feeling that you might solve it by using `useFetch` with POST (instead of the default GET).

Comment: Please, update the question to reflect your problem, this is required by SO rules. Even if the answer solved it, it may help other users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Python script, you're making a POST request.

The error message from your other code says you're making a GET request, which the endpoint doesn't handle (hence the 405 status code).

If the Python code is successful, then you should make a POST request in your other client, too.